# How to write unit tests for a sequence of data transformations?

Tags: python, r, unit-testing, tdd, testthat

I am trying to learn TDD while writing a script that transform its input data in a long series of functions. The problem is similar whether I write it in python or R. I guess it's more related to TDD understanding.

```
# Look of main in python
def main():
    data = get_data()
    data_a = transform_fun1(data)
    data_b = transform_fun2(data_a)
    data_c = transform_fun3(data_b)
    ....
    return data_x

# Look of main in R
main <- function() {
    data <- get_data() %>%
      transform_fun1() %>%
      transform_fun2() %>%
      transform_fun3() %>%
      ...
    data_x
}
```

What's the best process to write unit tests for each `transform_fun`, knowing that they need as input the result of the previous `transform_fun`?

In the beginning it looks fairly clean, but as I get further and further, I start to reproduce more and more of `main` in each test, which doesn't smell good. Reproducing entire parts of the `main` process looks counter-intuitive to the idea of unit testing.

```
# in python (pytest)
def test_transform_fun_n(data):
    data_a = transform_fun1(data)
    data_b = transform_fun2(data_a)
    ...
    data_n = transform_fun_n(data_n-1)
    assert data_n == blabla

# in R (testthat)
test_that("transform_fun_n do what I expect", {
    data_a <- transform_fun1(data)
    data_b <- transform_fun2(data_a)
    ...
    data_n <- transform_fun_n(data_n-1)
    expect_that(data_n, equals(blabla))
})
```

I also tried to add fixture between each step (at least in python) but it doesn't look ideal either.

-- EDIT --
Trying to sketch what VoiceOfUnreason's answer would look like.

```
def transformV1(data):
     return data + x

def transformV2(data):
     return transformV1(data) + y

def transformV3(data):
     return transformV2(data) + z

def main():
     data = get_data()
     return transformV3(data)
```

Comment: *I start to reproduce more and more of main in each test* - is there any more complex logic in `main()` than the sequence of calls shown in your code sample?

Comment: Currently I set a few values, but nothing that could not be put in one of the transformVx(data) functions.

Answer (score 1):

> In the beginning it looks fairly clean, but as I get further and further, I start to reproduce more and more of main in each test, which doesn't smell good. Reproducing entire parts of the main process looks counter-intuitive to the idea of unit testing.

Yes, you are right.  The code is trying tell you that your specifications (and your production code) are written at the wrong abstraction level.

```
def test_transformV1(data, expected):
    actual = transformV1(data)
    assert actual == expected

def main():
    data = getData()
    return transformV1(data)
```

When the requirements change, you write a *new* test, with the new specification

```
def test_transformV2(data, expected):
    actual = transformV2(data)
    assert actual == expected

def test_transformV1(data, expected):
    actual = transformV1(data)
    assert actual == expected

def main():
    data = getData()
    return transformV2(data)
```

The key ideas here being that (a) your unit tests exercise functions provided by your production code (b) new requirements mean a new function -- the new function may be implemented in terms of the others, but the test just checks that the new function returns the right result.

If main is hard to test (a common problem for [an imperative shell](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell)), then you want to make it as *thin* as you possibly can.

> make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies

Long chains of transformations need to be refactored from the shell to the core; given a name, and so on.

> Do you mean that code should be written more like what I added at the end of the question

Yes, that's the idea: the imperative shell accesses the functional core using the same entry point as one of the tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am still a bit confused. Do you mean that code should be written more like what I added at the end of the question (code looks unformatted in comments).

Answer (score 0):

Since you already identified a series of transformation functions, the logical course of action is to test them individually. Testing `main()`, on the other hand, is of questionable value as long as it remains a simple sequence of calls.

Because every function takes the result of the previous one as an input, you might be tempted to chain them in the test execution just like they are chained in the main program. However, this kind of defeats the *unit* test approach and might get you fixated on the happy path down to the final result, preventing you from exploring potentially problematic edge cases for input values at each step in the process.

Instead, try to rely on your function input types to come up with a bunch of tests with different input values that reflect various scenarios for each function. You can even use QuickCheck-like property-based tools to generate random values for you.